# Reuse r code with knitr in rnw / sweave files

Tags: r, latex, knitr, code-reuse, rnw

I'm searching for a way to reuse r-code in latex using knitr. I have multiple excel documents, that I want to import, analyze and plot in the same way throughout my thesis. Right now I am making a new .rnw file for each excel document that I have. This means, that if I want to change anything, I have to do it in every .rnw file - which seems like the wrong approach.  Is there a way, where I can call one .rnw file from the parent .rnw and providing it with an excel filename to import and work with.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. You can use both the `params` and `render` function to help with this. If you are unfamiliar with parameters look here [params](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html) and here for [render](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rmarkdown/versions/1.8/topics/render). I wrote iris and mtcars to excel for the examples below. In the markdown below I call the excel parameter in the chunk which is the excel file and just print the first 10 rows.

````
---
title: "iris"
output: pdf_document
params:
  excel: "G:/iris2.xlsx"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```



```{r cars}
head(xlsx::read.xlsx(params$excel,sheetIndex = 1))
```
````

Now to change the excel file you can use `lapply` and the render function in a .R file.

```
#create list of excel files
exldocs <- c("G:/mtcars2.xlsx", "G:/iris2.xlsx")

#call the renders.rmd (above), pass the list of excel files to overwrite the #default param field, output a new pdf (call it whatever you want)  
lapply(exldocs, function(x){
       rmarkdown::render("G:/renders.Rmd", params = list(excel = x),
                         output_file =paste0(substr(x,1,nchar(x)-4),"pdf")
                           )})
```

Comment: This is in markdown. I have written it in rnw. Is there an alternative? :) or should i just start using markdown in stead

Comment: Good question - sorry I thought your question said rmd. I do not have the rnw solution. However if you are interested in switching easily to rmd check out this function from the `knitr` package `knitr::Sweave2knitr()`.  Maybe also check out `knitr::render_sweave`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `knitr::knit` and use the `envir` argument as follows. Here is the `.Rnw` file

```latex
% parameterized_reports.Rnw
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<>>=
foo
@

\end{document}
```

Here is the R code

```r
tmp <- environment()
tmp$foo <- "xyz"
knitr::knit("parameterized_reports.Rnw", envir = tmp, output = "output.tex")
tools::texi2pdf("output.tex")
system('open output.pdf')
```

The result is

[image]